# React Native Navigation in a stateless component

Tags: react-native-navigation

I am trying to create stateless component  and I am struggling with the navigation and got this error ,  " undefined is not an object "

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please follow guidelines to posting questions. No images of codes or error messages. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by stateless component, but your error seems to be from this.props.navigation being undefined. Check the code where you wrote

```
<QRCodeCamera />
```

It should have a prop called navigation like this

```
<QRCodeCamera navigation={navigation} />
```